# Book or App to learn subtle differences between synomyms

Tags: differences, synonyms

I've been working on my English vocabulary for about 16 months now. I feel like I'm at a point at which I sometimes know different ways to express something I have in mind, but I struggle to choose the one that best fits the context.

Sometimes, I can find out if a word is more formal or literary, or conversely, if it comes from slang or is a colloquial word or expression, and also if it's a regional expression from NA, UK or AU which is helpful ... but it's not always the case.

So, I'm searching for a book, an app or any other media that would shed some light on these kind of questions.

Here are a few examples that are not meant to be answered but I put them here just to illustrate the kind of choice I have to make to express myself:

- lopsided, awry, slanted, askew, crooked
- scant, scanty, sparse, meagre
- to be loath/reluctant/unwilling/disinclined/averse to do sth,
- reckless, heedless, blithe, casual
- pander, fawn over/on one, cater for vs cater to (NA vs UK),
- to gleam/shine/shimmer/twinkle/glimmer/glisten/glance/glow
- stammer/stutter/splutter/falter
- mumble/mutter/whisper

On top of that, I can see that there are sometimes paradoxical definitions depending on the dictionary I'm referring to Collins, Lexico, Cambridge, The Free Dictionary (this one is useful for idioms), and every once in a while ... urban dictionary :)

Comment: Some of these have significant differences, such as *mumble* and *whisper*; others such as *loath* and *reluctant* perhaps less so.

Comment: You could do a Google search on the phrase in which you want to use the word. For example: _the human brain is ??_. There are over 400 results for _the human brain is lopsided_  but none at all for any of _lopsided's_ synonyms you list above. Similarly: _the star ?? brightly_. There are many results for _shine_ and _twinkle_ but only 1 for _glisten_ and none for _glance_. You could also investigate _concordancers_. For example: https://www.lextutor.ca/conc/

Comment: Belongs on meta. Voting for migration.

Comment: There are dictionaries of commonly confused words, e.g. Dave Dowling's Wrong Word Dictionary, which may help in some circumstances, but don't seem to exactly fulfil the requirements. An alternative would be to look up the word in a thesaurus and then look up each synonym in a good dictionary (with examples of usage).